# Blackberry Mobile application getting error when attempting to access a secure API?

Tags: blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I developed a Blackberry application using Eclipse.  The application is working fine in the simulator.  By using Blackberry desktop software, I tested the application in Blackberry mobile and it's working fine; but when I am using Progressbar screen, I am getting an error like this "Error starting Applicationname : Module 'ApplicationName' attempts to access a secure API."

How do I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to sign your application. read this article.

[Blackberry application signing](http://blog.vimviv.com/blackberry/blackberry-application-code-signing/)