# "module attempts to access a secure API" while working with Blackberry Curve 9360

Tags: blackberry, nfc, curve

I am working with Blackberry 9360 Curve on NFC embedded secure element.

I wrote an application for write something into the NFC embedded secure element. While running this application I am getting the error message as "Module attempts to access a secure API". I got the 3 keys installed, which is required for signing an application.

Is it necessary to get NFCR and RESE keys also. Can anybody have any idea about those keys and how to get them for my application or how to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

gsudesh

Comment: searching stackoverflow for "module secure API blackberry" turns up a number of relevant questions, such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731299/access-a-secure-api http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058998/blackberry-mobile-application-getting-error-when-attempting-to-access-a-secure-a http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377457/attempts-to-access-secure-api-error-in-blackberry

Answer (score 0):

You installed the signing keys, but did you actually use them to sign the compiled executable? Installation and Signing are separate operations.